# PayPal NVP : how use SunX509 on IBM JRE

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I’m integrating paypal Api for my company with NVP mode. The Application must be run on Websphere application Server.

In paypal SDK core, it actually uses in class SSLUtil (line 37) : KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509"). this does not work on IBM JRE. 
WAS uses IbmX509.

What can I do if I don’t want to modify the paypal class?

Thank you for you answer?

regards!

Stevens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following branch for you to get the fix. Please build and use that core with the SDK.

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/tree/fix-keymanagerfactory-ibm

Changed the SSLUtil Class as follows which should fix it for IBM as well as Oracle JRE.

KMF = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

We have made it agnostic of JRE provider.